# How to use nanosleep for sleeping random amounts of time?

Tags: c, random, delay

Im trying to use the function nanosleep to make my process sleep for a random amount of time between 1/10th of a second?

im using srand() to seed my random number generator, with the process id, that is, im calling:

```
srand(getpid());
```

then using

```
struct timespec delay;
delay.tv_sec = 0;
delay.tv_nsec = rand();
nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
```

How can i make sure im sleeping for 0..1/10th of a second?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you just need `100000000ULL * rand() / RAND_MAX` nanoseconds, this is at most 0.1s and at least 0s. Alternatively, try `usleep()` with argument `100000ULL * rand() / RAND_MAX`. (I think `usleep` requires fewer CPU resources.)

(*Edit:* Added "unsigned long long" literal specifier to ensure that the number fits. See comments below, and thanks to caf for pointing this out!)

Comment: Actually, on Linux the C library implements `usleep` by calling `nanosleep`.  So your two suggestions have identical performance.  `nanosleep` is preferable because it is specified by POSIX.

Comment: `100000000 * rand()` is likely to overflow most of the time, given typical values of `INT_MAX` and `RAND_MAX`.  `100000000.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX` is safe.

Comment: @Nemo: Thanks! @Caf: How about `100000000ULL * ((unsigned long long int) rand()) / (unsigned long long int)RAND_MAX`?

Comment: The casts shouldn't be necessary, the other values should get promoted up by math with the `ULL` literal. `intmax_t` (and `INTMAX_C()`) might be better suited to the problem.

Comment: @Chris Lulz: Thanks! I'm never really confident about the promotion rules, hence my paranoia. Here's a [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/intmax_t) about those constants, in case the OP wants to use those -- it appears that you have to define some macro and include stdint.h to get those; I'll leave it up to the OP to work out the details.

Answer (score 0):

you need to "cap" your rand(), like:

```
delay.tv_nsec = rand() % 1e8;
```

Some experts say that this is not the optimal way to do it, because you use the LSB of the number and they are not as "random" as the higher bits, but this is fast and reliable.

Comment: If you need to use `rand` many millions of times and don't care about having an even distribution, using a modulo instead of converting it to a floating-point type and doing division _might_ be a better approach. In any other situation there is no excuse for using a half-assed answer that you know is wrong. -1

Comment: It also assumes `RAND_MAX >> 1e8`. It's ~32k on all the implementations I've seen.

Comment: @aib you must be using ancient stuff. In this linux virtual box i just opened here, RAND_MAX is equal INT_MAX (32bit) (2147483647). @Chris suit yourself